# What does double digitized polygon mean?

Tags: polygon, geometry

I know what is a polygon but when a polygon is said to be double digitized?  I failed to find a suitable meaning of double digitized after googling. I understand double digitized means digitized twice, so I hope it would be enough if someone explains what does digitized polygon mean. I found the term double digitized from source . [ESRI Shapefile Technical Description (page 1)](https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf)

Comment: I think you should always try using search engines prior to posting e.g. http://www.google.com/search?q=double+digitized

Comment: I asked the question because I failed to find a suitable meaning of double digitized after googling. I am completely new in this area so it would be  great help if one explains the meaning of the term double digitized.

Comment: Your question does not mention that you googled or that you found any definition for the term you are asking about. You can address this by using the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I [googled for "double digitized"](http://www.google.com/search?q=double%20digitized) the fourth non-paid result was the Practical Handbook of Digital Mapping Terms and Concepts by Sandra Arlinghaus:

> **double-digitized polygons**
>
> when polygons are recorded as closed loops of coordinates, the first and last coordinates are the same; therefore, boundaries of
>   adjacent polygons are digitized twice.

I would also call it double-digitizing any time the same polygon is inadvertently digitized a second time.

Comment: In the context of the OP's research, the more general definition, of polygons stored as rings (vice a directed graph of arcs) probably holds sway.